# Git merge 2 versions

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

So I have a project on which me and another guy, are doing our thing. We are using 'git' for version control. Now, he has his own branch "version2" and I have my branch "version 1". We both have committed and pushed our versions to the repo but now how do we merge our projects together?

What I did was pulled his version on my system using `git clone https:url.git -b version2` in a new directory. Then I tried to checkout to my branch(version1) and merge version2 to it but it said `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.

Then I tried `git pull https:url.git` but I got `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

[image]

So this is what I am trying to do. David and Alice pull from origin, do their thing and now to continue both their work they need to synchronise their versions.

Comment: Did you start off with two separate repositories? Why?

Comment: we both started off with the same repo, did our thing and then pushed our versions to the repo. Now we need to do some more of our stuff but before that, we need to combine both our work.

Comment: @nupac Did you not have one person push, then have the other fetch and merge, then push again?

Comment: If you mean after doing our modifications then yes, thats what we are doing. He pushed, I fetched and am trying to merge but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont' clone. This creates new repo instance.
Checkout remote branch.

```
git checkout -b version2 origin/version2
```

Then switch back to your branch

```
git checkout version1
```

Finally you can merge version2 branch into version1 branch

```
git merge version2
```

Merge will be successful if there is no conflicts. At last push your changes to repo.

There is great book about git for begginers http://git-scm.com/book/en/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply but I have this error `fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/version2' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Comment: Did you fetch branches? Try git branch -a. If you won't see origin/version2 do git fetch --all and then try to checkout branch.

Comment: @nupac Your version1 and his version2 seems not in same remote repository, so before checkout, you need add remote repo of version2 on your local repo, then do `git checkout -b version2 RemoteOfVersion2/version2` and do other merge job.

Comment: I had to do it all over again and it worked this time. Something might have gone wrong the first time